# Socket output response not reaching client

Tags: java, sockets

Hi have a socket client that successfully prints to the output stream. The server retrieves it and tries to return the response string on the output stream. However, the response never reaches the client, despite the fact that I can see the debugging trigger on the `readLine()` method in the client.

Client side snippet

```
       protected static BufferedReader getClientInputChannel() {
            BufferedReader inFromServer = null;
            try {
                if (clientSocket != null)
                    clientSocket = new Socket(TPS_HOST, TPS_PORT);
                inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return inFromServer;
        }


        if (query != null && !query.isEmpty()) {                
                    System.out.println("RetrievalSystem: send query: " + query);
                    outToServer.println(query);
                    String response = getClientInputChannel().readLine();
                    System.out.println("RetrievalSystem: response from TPS: " + response);
                    // Close the output stream.
                    outToServer.close();
                }
```

Server side.

```
package com.ds;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.List;

public class TextProcessingServer extends Thread {
    protected final static int DEFAULT_TPS_PORT = 8081;

    protected int port;

    public TextProcessingServer(int defaultTpsPort) {
        setPort(defaultTpsPort);
    }

    public TextProcessingServer() {
        setPort(DEFAULT_TPS_PORT);
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        init();
    }

    /**
     * single threaded query consumer.
     */
    protected void init() {
        System.out.println("Initializing TPS Server.");
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(getPort());
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            // set up the read and write end of the communication socket
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter outToClient =
                    new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true); 

            // retrieve first line of request and set up for parsing
            String requestMessageLine = inFromClient.readLine();

            while (requestMessageLine.length() > 0) {
                System.out.println("TPS SERVER: Incoming request: " + requestMessageLine);
                // Send reply       
                    // THIS REPLY NEVER REACHES THE CLIENT.
                outToClient.println(queryInvertedIndex(requestMessageLine));
                // Now, listen again for the next incoming request.
                requestMessageLine = inFromClient.readLine();
            }

            System.out.println("left client listening mode.");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out
                    .println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                            + getPort() + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                clientSocket.close();
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public String queryInvertedIndex(String queryString) {
        InvertedIndex invIdx = InvertedIndex.getInstance();
        // There could be multiple query strings, thus split.
        // Also handle html encoded strings: pigs%20fly
        String queryStrings[] = queryString.split("%20|\\s");
        StringBuilder resultList = new StringBuilder();
        for (String key : queryStrings) {
            List<Integer> partialResultList = invIdx.get(key);
            for (Integer lineNumber : partialResultList)
                resultList.append(lineNumber.toString() + " ");
            resultList.replace(resultList.length() - 1, resultList.length(),
                    ", ");
        }
        // Remove the last comma.
        if (resultList.length() > 0)
            resultList = new StringBuilder(resultList.substring(0,
                    resultList.length() - 2));
        else
            resultList = new StringBuilder("[NO_RESULT]");
        return resultList.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: `if (clientSocket != null)
                    clientSocket = new Socket(TPS_HOST, TPS_PORT);` maybe the cause, but it is impossible to be sure without seeing your definitions for `clientSocket` and `outToServer`

Comment: That’s the weirdest use of a `StringBuilder` I have ever seen… Do you know *why* you have augmented your `String` manipulations with these additional `StringBuilder` operations?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are forgetting to flush the output stream.

```
outToClient.flush();
```

try that..

Comment: I created the PrintWriter object with the option AutoFlush = true. It is supposed to flush immediately. I tried manually flush before. Does not seem to be the problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: try write method instead of println

Comment: Is this a LF/CRLF thing, maybe?

Comment: try write method instead of println and flush it.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, I read something about that a line's end need to be marked specifically. I only submit a simple string. I need to check how to demark the end of a line.

Comment: @rajj What is that? method instead of println? Do not know what you mean.

Comment: ya, it will write your string on output stream of client socket. I have also faced this problem at beginning. just try that one once.use write method outToClient.write(response); outToClient.flush();

Comment: Ah, you mean write() instead of println(). Nope, thread still remains on the readLine(). Still waiting to receive something.

Comment: ya, man it is blocking call. so it will wait until something is there.but with write and flush your response will reach to client.

Comment: what you should do is after accepting request span separate thread that will read from stream and write response. With this approach you won't be able to accept another request because accept method is not able to hit again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39741/discussion-between-rajj-and-feder)

Comment: @rajj I do not need to handle multiple request. Just that very single one-time request.

Comment: okay, why do you need printWriter here, why don't you use BufferedWriter.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. It is something that you could not see. I called the server from a **static class**. Changing the class into a non-static class with no static methods helped.